# Controller and API DTO Architecture and class organization in .net core with microservices

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, controller, class-design

We are developing a system with coarse microservice architecture. We have an API that uses controllers and back-end logic with Entity-Framework repository, and several types of clients that use this API, all in dotnet, therefore, typesafe.

We need to use some sort of data transfer objects for communication between the API and the clients. Clients are using REST calls. However, our controllers need to hide some properties of the entities for:

- different clients (e.g. metadata of entity for web clients and no metadata for mobile clients)
- different controller actions (e.g. `/Users/` returns a list of `User` DTOs having only name and surname, whereas `/Users/{id}` returns user details. )
- different REST methods (e.g. a `Post` requests would not have timestamps as it is created server-side)

My question is: what would be a good design for reusability? Is the best practice creating new classes for all requests/responses? We wouldn't want to use dynamic objects. I thought of Builder pattern, but I am not sure if that fits here.

Answer (score 3):

From my point of view when you speak of *hiding* you need to design your interface explicitly for every case **in order not to show data accidentially** to someone who is not allowed to see it.

Here is a sample to get you the idea:

[image]

As stated before you would explicitly expose your API. Meaning you would have two controllers: *MobileClientController* and *WebClientController*. Both share a common *BaseController* for common tasks.

The DTOs that are exposed need to be explicitly declared to make sure that no member will be accidentially shown to somebody who is not allowed to see it.

Here are my code listings for all the mentioned files:

**BaseController.cs**

```
[Authorize]
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    // Common Tasks
}
```

**MobileClientController.cs** make sure that only MobileClient are allowed `[Authorize(Roles = "MobileClient")]`

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Authorize(Roles = "MobileClient")]
public class MobileClientController : BaseController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<MobileClientDto> Get()
    {
        // query data and map to List<MobileClientDto>
        return new List<MobileClientDto>();
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public MobileClientDetailDto Get(int id)
    {
        // query data and map to MobileClientDetailDto
        return new MobileClientDetailDto();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        var model = new MobileClientDetailDto()
        {
            Browser = value
        };

        // save logic
    }
}
```

**WebClientController.cs** make sure that only WebClients are allowed `[Authorize(Roles = "WebClient")]`

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Authorize(Roles = "WebClient")]
public class WebClientController : BaseController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WebClientDto> Get()
    {
        // query data and map to List<WebClientDto>
        return new List<WebClientDto>();
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public WebClientDetailDto Get(int id)
    {
        // query data and map to WebClientDetailDto
        return new WebClientDetailDto();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        var model = new WebClientDetailDto()
        {
            DetailedProperty = value
        };

        // save logic
    }
}
```

And finally the DTOs:

**BaseClientDto.cs**

```
public class BaseClientDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**MobileClientDetailDto.cs**

```
public class MobileClientDetailDto : MobileClientDto
{
    public string Browser { get; set; }
}
```

**MobileClientDto.cs**

```
public class MobileClientDto : BaseClientDto
{
}
```

**WebClientDetailDto.cs**

```
public class WebClientDetailDto : WebClientDto
{
    public string DetailedProperty { get; set; }
}
```

**WebClientlDto.cs**

```
public class WebClientDto : BaseClientDto
{
    public string MetadataProperty { get; set; }
}
```